# How can i use param in path as prop react router dom v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a route `<Route path="post/:id" element={<PostByIdPage />} />`

How can i get param `id` as `props` in react router dom **v6**?

Here is my PostByIdPage component :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import OneSecret from '../OneSecret';
import getSecretsPublic from '../../../action/getSecretsPublic';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


export class index extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            secretPublic: {
                content: ''
            }
        }
        let id = decodeURI(window.location.pathname.substring(6));
        let params = {
            id: id
        }
        this.props.getSecretsPublic(params)
            .then(res =>{
                if (res.type === 'ERROR_MESSAGE') {
                    return;
                }
                this.setState({secretPublic: res.payload.data[0]})
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <OneSecret element={this.state.secretPublic} key={this.state.secretPublic.id} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default connect(null, {getSecretsPublic})(index)
```

I'm using window.location.pathname and split to get param but i want to get params from props to re render() my component based in params

Answer (score 5):

Little late to answer but you can achieve it easily.
<this.props.match> will be available once you use {useParams} from react-router-dom but its a little tricky for class-based components.
If using functional component, you have a choice of directly using {useParams} and props.match will be available.
For Class-based components like your case, You can do this with High order component:

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
export function withRouter(Children) {
  return (props) => {
    const match = { params: useParams() };
    return <Children {...props} match={match} />
  }
}
class PostByIdPage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
         <h1>Page for {this.props.match.params.id}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default withRouter(PostByIdPage);
```

Now in you classbased component, You can access id as:

```
this.props.match.params.id
```

No more Error for ' this.props.match is undefined'

Comment: This is perfect!!!

Answer (score 1):

i think its the same as before you can use useParams()
like this:

```
let { id } = useParams();
```

**update:**

```
<Route path= "third/:id"  element={Content}/>
```

this is my code to call to the component
and this is the component:

```
 class Content extends Component {
    componentDidMount () {

        console.log( this.props.match.params.id );
    }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
         <h1>Third</h1>
      </div>

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i'm using class so i can't use hooks

Comment: can you please send me PostByIdPage  this component code

Comment: one of the problem can be due to props try to console log this.props

Comment: i hope whati do as update help you,
well i most use react-roter-dom v5.2 but as i read its the same  so thisi s what i use in my project transfer to v6

Comment: useParams() doesn't work in class components, and router v6 doesn't pass in  match.params any more

Comment: @adavea if you look at the code i also put the class component one 
and by the date of this answer this code is for v5 and not v6

Answer (score -1):

you will get it as `this.props.match.params.id` in `PostByIdPage` component.

Comment: how can i get match, this.props.match is undefind

Comment: I think with react router latest version, you have to use declare your route as :

<Route
    path="/<route>/:id"
    render={({ match }) => <PostByIdPage match={match} />}
  />

check the following link for more details:

https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v5-1/

Comment: Have you tried this in v6?  They changed how params work in v6 and you are linking to v5 docs